# How can i change only the changing value in flutter signalr?

Tags: flutter, dart, signalr, signalr.client

I cannot setup the logic. I have three values. You know signalr only changing value comes. When i tried to change, every values change. Here is my code part=>

```
Text(a![0].name == 'PLC201.val'
                      ? '${a![0].value}': checkValue(a![0], a![0].name!)),
Text(a![0].name == 'PLC202.val'
                      ? '${a![0].value}': checkValue(a![0], a![0].name!)),
Text(a![0].name == 'PLC203.val'
                      ? '${a![0].value}': checkValue(a![0], a![0].name!)),
...

checkValue(SignalRModel a, String name) {
    var value;
    if(name == 'PLC201.val'){
      return value = a.value;
    } else if(name == 'PLC202.val'){
      return value = a.value;
    } else {
      return value = a.value;
    }
  }
...
SignalRModel {
  String? name;
  String? value;
  String? customCode;
}
```

This is my output from signalr =>
**[{"Name":"PLC201.val","Value":"32,69906","CustomCode":"EGS"}]**

Where is the problem? Is anyone help me to solve this? I only update the changing value.

Comment: `checkValue` always returns `a.value`, no matter what. All three `Text` widgets will also always display the same exact text, because they display either `a[0]!.value` or... `a[0]!.value`. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but that might be part of the problem.

Comment: You're also assigning to the variable `value` in checkValue, but that assignment does nothing, since `value` immediately goes out of scope.

Comment: Bro outputs come this format [{"Name":"PLC201.val","Value":"32,69906","CustomCode":"EGS"}]
[{"Name":"PLC202.val","Value":"32,906","CustomCode":"EGS"}], how can i check it, there is a way to solve it?

Comment: Yes. Like I said, your `checkValue` function does nothing - it may as well not exist. And your Text widgets will all always display the same value, no matter what. Those issues will need to be fixed before any other issues can be addressed

Comment: bro there is only one value, how to fetch it? how can i modify the checkValue method?

Comment: @MichaelHorn do you have any ideas?